# How to get element's (defined as TagHelper) content in TagHelper.Process?

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

How to get elements defined as TagHelper content?

E.g. element defined as:

```html
<markdown>bla bla</markdown>
```

And helper defined as:

```cs
[HtmlTargetElement("markdown")]
public class MarkdownTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        var c = output.Content.GetContent(); 
        // c is empty; how to get content "bla bla"?
    }
}
```

Comment: Is that at runtime or design time? If it's the second you could find all classes implementing `ITagHelper`in the assemblies added in your `_ViewImports.cshtml`. In the first case I don't know if ASP.Net Core exposes such information

Comment: At runtime. Content of element. Inside TagHelper.Proccess.

Comment: Ah, I totally misread the question. Yes, that is possible using`output.GetChildContentAsync()`

Comment: see also this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55076134/2803565

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `output.GetChildContentAsync()` as explained in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring#inspecting-and-retrieving-child-content) (worth reading as it contains a few examples that retrieve the element's contents).

You will then implement your tag helper as in:

```
public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
{
      var c = (await output.GetChildContentAsync()).GetContent(); 
      // transform markdown in c
}
```